# Selenium IDE and VAADIN

Tags: selenium, vaadin, ui-automation

I'm trying to generate some automated tests with Selenium on a site that is using VAADIN. I'm using the IDE to familiarize myself with the initial setup of the testing scripts; currently using a Mac with FireFox 50.1.0 and Selenium IDE 2.9.1.

Things were going fairly well until I needed to click on and select a row from a table generated by VAADIN. It seems like mouseDown/MouseUp, click, nor any sendkey key combinations I have tried will select a row; the nearest I've gotten so far to changing a tr class="v-table-row" to tr class="v-table-row v-selected" has been setting focus on the row...but can't select.

Searches so far seem to hint that Selenium and VAADIN can't be made to get along well; am I missing something that would tell Selenium IDE to click and select that row in the table?

Does the webdriver version work better with interacting with VAADIN?

Or do I need to find another way to test the interface with automated testing?

Comment: To be fair, I haven't used selenium in a while and I know they developed [TestBench](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/testbench/testbench-overview.html) (based on Selenium) for Ajax compatibility and some Vaadin related convenience APIs, but for a trivial task as this Selenium should suffice. I know it's been a while since you asked, but if you're still interested please share a complete example to reproduce your problem.